# Sequences of positive real number

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose  that $(a_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(b_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ are sequences of positive real number, and that $$\limsup\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} < \infty\;.$$ Prove that there is a constant $M$ so that $a_{n}\le Mb_{n}$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: LaTeX directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: There isn’t an actual FAQ section any longer; the most relevant links are [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Oops, true! What happened? There should at least be a special section with a special name where it's explained how to write mathematics in this site...

Comment: @DonAntonio: It seems to be part of the current batch of site-wide revision. And I definitely agree with that last bit; **I** have a hard time remembering where to find the bloomin’ things. // I rolled back to parentheses: they’re pretty standard to distinguish sequences from sets, so there seems to be no good reason to change the OP’s notation there.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a_n\leq Mb_n$ is the same as $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}\leq M$, and that $\left(\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}\right)$ is just another sequence of positive numbers.  So let's simplify this to a more general (but equivalent) statement:

> If $(c_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n<\infty$, then there is a positive constant $M$ such that $c_n\leq M$ for all $n\geq 1$.

It helps to give a name to the limsup, say $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n = A$.  By definition, $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n = \inf\limits_{n\geq 1}\sup\limits_{k\geq n}c_k = A$.  By definition of inf, this means that if we take any number $A'$ larger than $A$, then there will exist an $n_0$ such that $\sup\limits_{k\geq n_0}c_k<A'$.  For example, we can take $A'=A+1$, and there exists $n_0$ such that $\sup\limits_{k\geq n_0}c_k<A+1$. This gives us an upper bound for all of the terms $c_n$ with $n\geq n_0$.  For the rest, note that there are only finitely many so it is possible to find a bound for them, and combine the bounds to find $M$.

To summarize the $2$ main ingredients:

- Every number larger than the limsup is eventually an upper bound for the terms in the sequence.
- A sequence is bounded if it is eventually bounded.

Answer (score -1):

Hints: Suppose

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L\implies \exists\,K\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>K\implies1>\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}-L\right|\ge\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|-L$$

Well, what happens in you choose $\;M:=L+1\;$ ...?

Note: above, one has to assume in fact that the first equality on the left is for a *subsequence* $\,\frac{a_{n_k}}{b_{n_k}}\,$ of $\,\frac{a_n}{b_n}\,$ , but this is easy to fix...

Comment: $M=L+1$ might not work, but I guess you're leaving readers to discover this intentionally?  Also, you are deliberately assuming the limit exists instead of working with the limsup?

Comment: The subindexes for the lim sup is a miss, the other one was intentional for taking the maximum of $\;\frac{a_1}{b_1},...,\frac{a_K}{b_K}\,$ and $\,M\,$ itself . Thanks